# Multi-tenant microservice security

Tags: security, cloud, microservices

In short I'm implementing a cloud for my boss. This cloud will be mainly used by angular2 based front-end applications, including mobile application. This cloud must have multi-tenant support so the company can monetize this investment. He prefers not to be reliant on third party providers.

As a platform I intend to use the wso2 products as the ecosystem of the cloud. Information can be found [here](http://wso2.com/platform). The one for this question is the wso2 identity server (installation on premise). you can find more information [here](http://wso2.com/identity-and-access-management).

The micro-services will be based upon [spring cloud](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/).

For security I want to implement [this](http://nordicapis.com/how-to-control-user-identity-within-microservices/) OAuth2 pattern, where an opaque token is shared with the front-end and an enterprise service bus translates this inbound token to an identity token containing RBAC information to provide stateless identity within the cloud.

This is the part where it becomes unclear. For securing front-end applications I need an identity store. For web applications it is preferred to use the email and password combination for login. When I look to OpenLDAP or similar, I tend to find username and password combination. What technology would be best suited as identity provider using email and password combinations with role based access control and multitenancy? Perhaps I'm still missing some basic understanding, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenLDAP has everything needed to accomplish this. You can lookup a user via its email address and then you can authenticate the user further. Wso2is has everything needed to make this work. It is just simple configuration. Information can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Using+Email+Address+as+the+Username).

Answer (score 0):

Please check JWT. OAuth needs another authentication server to Authenticate & Authorize users. JWT is best suited way for microservices architecture.

You just need to **verify the JWT token's signature**. Check whether it's signed by any of your microservice or not to Authenticate the User(it's simple).

For implementing Authorization, you can add role level information in your JWT token when you are generating the token.

Such that, UI would always access your services with the token and you would always get this information in your JWT token in all the microservices. Make use of Spring security to provide access of certain resources based on the Role.

Please check out this [blog](https://medium.facilelogin.com/securing-microservices-with-oauth-2-0-jwt-and-xacml-d03770a9a838) for more information on securing your microservices.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx for the effort, but It doesn't seem like an answer to my question. I know about the flow and the role of Oauth. Where I'm unclear is that authentication server. You have tech like openLDAP or Active Directory. I would like to know what production grade authentication server would best suit the multi-tenant architecture, with email/password parameters for authentication.